# Remove element in form JS

Tags: javascript, dom

Now I'm a bit stuck in deleting an item from a form.
my code below ain't doing what I want and I don't know how to fix it.
Basically I want to remove the TD line from my form when I click on the trash icon, so I created this function that create the TD element and add the trash icon clickable, but what the code is doing is remove the trash icon and not the TD...
I'm wondering how to get the index of the element from a form but didnt realized yet, so I've tried using the this.remove() statment but didnt worked.
I'm glad with any help.
Cheers

```
function montaTdBtn() {
let _td;
let _a;
let _img;
_td = document.createElement('td');
_td.setAttribute('class', 'buttn-tr');

_a = document.createElement('a');
_a.setAttribute('href', '#');

_img = document.createElement('img');
_img.setAttribute('src', 'favicon.ico');
_img.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.remove();

});
_a.appendChild(_img);
_td.appendChild(_a);

return _td;
}
```

Comment: Does “removeChild” work? Or maybe “remove”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `parentNode`.

```
_img.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.parentNode.remove();
});
```

Since you have a reference to the `<td>` element, you can directly remove that as well.

```
_img.addEventListener("click", function () {
    _td.remove();
});
```

Comment: Should I pass _td as parameter in the function?
Because when I do it still removing the icon and not the TD.

Comment: That should not be the case. Would you mind providing a [mcve] with the modified code?

Comment: https://share.getcloudapp.com/qGuNDxEQ

Maybe helps more.

Comment: OMG, watching the video I've realized that my code is doing the rigth thing.
What I need to do is delete the TR and not the TD...
Thank you for your patience.
Im really felling stupid haha